# How to remove ant?

Tags: java, macos, apache, ant

First I ran these commands in my terminal to manually install ant.

```
# Let's get into your downloads folder.
tar -xvzf apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz # Extract the folder
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local # Ensure that /usr/local exists
sudo cp -rf apache-ant-1.9.4-bin /usr/local/apache-ant # Copy it into /usr/local

# Add the new version of Ant to current terminal session
export PATH=/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:"$PATH"

# Add the new version of Ant to future terminal sessions
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:"$PATH"' >> ~/.profile

# Demonstrate new version of ant
ant --version
```

When I ran the last command, it showed an error. I then used brew to install ant which worked. Can I remove the first set of commands somehow? If so how? or does it not matter?

Comment: this is not a programming question at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the shell you are using, so .profile will get executed.

If you really want to use the same shell, you can run manually:

```
source ~/.profile
```